# How to connect to two different clusters?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-cassandra

Is it possible using spring-boot 2.1.x (with spring-data-cassandra 2.*) to connect to two different clusters?

If that is possible, how do I bind a Repository (or Template, or CRUDRepository) to one of the clusters?

Could I use the same template (and possibly creating two beans from it) against both clusters?
Say I'd like to store data in a "hot" cluster with short TTL and also in a "cold" cluster with longer TTL (made up example so don't criticise the actual use case ;))

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `AbstractRoutingSessionFactory`. You can use this base class to build your own `Session` router based on e.g. `ThreadLocal` storage. The tricky bit is to know when to switch between sessions.

You can also generalize the concept by implementing your own `SessionFactory` that is controlled by a circuit breaker or a setting to which `Session` calls get routed. All this happens transparently. Just make sure to configure your own `CassandraTemplate` bean to pick up the `SessionFactory` as Spring Boot defaults to a single `Session`.

Repositories work on top of the `CassandraTemplate` bean.

Comment: It seems to me that if I create two clusters the autoconfigaration from CassandraDataAutoConfiguration complains about more than one Cluster bean ...